# iOS - set maximum width for UILabel with Autolayout

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, uilabel

I have a `UILabel` contained in a `UIView` that has a fixed size. The `UILabel` has dynamic text. How can I make sure that the `UILabel` will never get bigger than the containing UIView?

Before using `AutoLayout` this was quite simple to achieve by simply using the `AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`, but I can't manage to get this working with Autolayout anymore.

What contraints should I add from the `UILabel` to the `UIView`? Right now it is simply Leading aligned.

Comment: width <= superview.width

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are special methods for such views like `UILabel` (`contentHugging` and `contentCompressionResistance`), but they are already enabled. So all you need to disable label's width grow to superview's width.

```
NSLayoutConstraint *widthConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.label attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual toItem:self.label.superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];    
[self.label addConstraint:widthConstraint];
```

Comment: Your comment on the question worked really good, just one thing: how can I then adapt the UILabel's font size so that it will fit into the maximum width I  gave it?

Comment: myLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
myLabel.minimumScaleFactor = .5f;
This worked for me ! Thanks a lot TImur

Answer (score 0):

I will add left, top, right constraints as the following:

[image]

In storyboard, it is simply several clicks:

- Select your label
- In the add constraints panel (bottom right), select the constraints you want to add

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Drag and resize your label to fit full width of screen, may be leave some padding from both side.
Set 4 constraints :
1) height of Label.
2) Top space to UIView.
3) leading space to UIView.
4) Trailing space to UIView.

And lastly make horizontalcompressionResistense priority of Label to 1000.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3 and 4**

```
var widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .lessThanOrEqual, toItem: label.superview, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
label.addConstraint(widthConstraint)
```